# How can I open, read and write Non-english text file (i.e Gujarati) in python 3.5?

Tags: python-3.x, nlp

I am newbie to the python programming, so I do not know how basic this question is. I Want to process a Gujarati text file in python 3.5. When I tried to execute this block of code, it gave me an error. How can i fix this error?

```
import tkinter.filedialog
import fileinput
import tkinter

filename1 = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfile()


my_file = open(filename1, "r", encoding= "utf-16")

content = my_file.read()

print(content)
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\PhD\python workspace\guj.py", line 8, in <module>
    my_file = open(filename1, "r", encoding= "utf-16")
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='D:/PhD/python    workspace/text files/Gujarati.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not in the language. That should not matter, as the computer only sees the file as a collection of characters.

The issue is that `askopenfile` returns the path of a directory, not a file. Then the code tries to open the directory for reading, which gives the `invalid file` error you saw.

What you should use instead is `askopenfilename`, which will ask the user to select a file, not a directory.